# Defining a word using Regex in R

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to define a word in R. I'd like to include words that contain punctuation within them (i.e. hyphens, like "sugar-free" and contractions, such as "don't") as well as words that contain numbers, like 7th or 10th. 
I've gotten as far as this:

```
gregexpr("[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*
```

I'm likely missing something related to a period (`.`), but I am not sure how to add this.

Comment: So what things is your current regular expression messing that you also want to catch. I don't see a clear statement of what exactly your problem is. You need to be very explicit in your matching criteria.

Comment: Apologies. I'm new to this. It's missing words that have apostrophes or hyphens in them. For example, I want to include words like "it's" and "I'm" as one word.

Comment: So then just add apostrophes to your regex: `gregexpr("[a-zA-Z0-9']+")`. Is that all you needed?

Comment: Almost-- what if I wanted apostrophes and hyphens. Can I just add a hyphen, too: gregexpr("[a-zA-Z0-9'-]+")? This doesn't seem like it would work, as hyphens have other meaning.

Comment: Yes, but you have to escape it since hyphens are special characters in regular expressions: `gregexpr("[a-zA-Z0-9'\\-]+")`

Comment: Oh right! Thank you very much. I'm sorry to bother you with such basics. Hopefully I'll get the hang of this better soon!

Comment: I looked at the stringi package and tried it, but it does not handle hyphens, it appears:  string <- c("sugar-free", "don't", "wordthree", "word four", "sugar*free")

stringi::stri_extract_words(str = string) [[1]]
[1] "sugar" "free"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can continue to define characters you want to include/match by adding them to your [**character class**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

```
gregexpr("[a-zA-Z0-9'-]+", x)
                    ^^
```

**Note:** Inside of a character class the hyphen has **special meaning**. You can place the hyphen as the first or last character of the class. In some regex implementations, you can also place directly after a range. If you place the hyphen anywhere else you need to precede it with two backslashes in order to add it to your class.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the additional characters that you want inside the square brackets. Since hyphens have a semantic meaning (denoting ranges of characters), either put it first, last or escape it as `\-`:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9'-]+
[-a-zA-Z0-9']+
[a-zA-Z0-9\-']+
```

Comment: In R you need to escape the slash as well in the string, so the last one would be "[a-zA-Z0-9\\-']+"